# Is there a way to disable a function for arguments that are temporary objects?

Tags: c++, c++20, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

Consider a function like this:

```
auto&& just(auto&& arg) { return std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg); }
```

This will perfect-forward all the references and will return a dead reference when called for a temporary object.

In more details:

```
struct Something {};
auto something() { return Something{}; }

auto&& ref = just(something()); // ERROR: Here ref refers to already destructed Something.

auto&& hold = something();
auto&& ref = just(hold);   // OK: Here ref refers to lifetime-extended Something.
```

So the question is: how can one define `just`, so the first call will fail to compile, while the second call will compile?

Comment: Require a _lvalue reference_?

Comment: `just(auto&& arg)`, um, what version of C++ are you using? That function shouldn't compile in c++11, 14, or 17 without `-fconcepts`.

Comment: @Elliott Yes, `gcc-9.3` with `-std=c++17 -fconcepts`

Comment: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#t150-check-that-a-class-matches-a-concept-using-static_assert

Comment: I believe you should think again about your accepted answer :-)

Comment: @Klaus What's wrong with the answer? Consider a more generic case when you got some concept instead of `auto`, like this: `template <SSomeConcept Arg> Arg&& just(Arg&& arg)`. `SSomeConcept` might include both reference and non-reference types. requires `std::is_reference_v<Arg>` will handle the situation, right?

Comment: @Vahagn, you want to reject any rvalue and accept and lvalue, right? Defining your function with `just(Arg& arg)` will always reject the rvalues regardless of what `Arg` is (including a concept). If `Arg` is a concept that is rejecting lvalues, then you have a problem, but the problem is in your concept and so isn't relevant to answers here.

Comment: @Elliott "you want to reject any rvalue and accept and lvalue, right?" - No! I just want to reject temporaries. So `just(std::move(hold))` is also something that should be accepted.

Comment: @Vahagn, how is the compiler supposed to know that difference? `std::move` just casts lvalues to rvalues. That's it.

Comment: @Elliott Yes, you guys are right! I messed it up a little bit.

Comment: @Vahagn, no problem. Also, the concept answer wouldn't have worked when the type of the template argument is rvalue. So `just<Something&&>(std::move(hold))` would compile, which I think wasn't what AndyG meant to do. It could've easily been fixed by changing it to something like `requires std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>`, or more intuitively `is_lvalue_reference_v<T&&>`.

Answer (score 0):

As `πάντα ῥεῖ` pointed out in the comments, if you require an lvalue then you should write your function that way (single `&`):

[from your comment, I've used c++17 style]

```
template <typename Arg>
auto && just(Arg & arg);
```

However, I'll consider your real world problem isn't so simple and that you prefer to code the requirements inside the function:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Arg>
auto && just(Arg && arg) {

    static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<Arg&&>);

    return std::forward<Arg>(arg);
}
```

Example: It's practical for a function to do some work then return the output of a function with perfect forwarding to avoid copies, but you need to check its return type. For those not able to use `concepts` it's neater to do the check inside the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Func>
auto && just (Func && func)
{
    using return_type = decltype(func());
    
    static_assert(std::is_reference_v<return_type>, "returning temportary");

    // calculate arguments for func
    // (no args here for simplicity)

    return func(); // always return ref
}

int global;
int ReturnCopy () { return int(); }
int & ReturnGlobal () { return global; }
int && ReturnTemporary () { return std::move(global); }

int main ()
{
    just(ReturnCopy); // <--- error
    just(ReturnGlobal);
    just(ReturnTemporary);
}
```